# In Dapper Multiple Results how do you get the second line query to work when the where clause depends upon the result of the first query?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Get List of customers with their related orders and returns
sample:

```
var sql = @"select * from Customers
select * from Orders where CustomerId = (depends on first query)
select * from Returns where CustomerId = (depends on first query)";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
{
   var customer = multi.Read<Customer>().ToList();
   var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
   var returns = multi.Read<Return>().ToList();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is ultimately an SQL question. There is nothing extra or different dapper does here - if you issue multiple selects as a batch, they must be valid SQL. There are several ways of doing that, involving:

- local sql variables (typically if one row)
- temporary tables or (better) table variables
- joins or sub-queries
- etc

If you can't construct SQL to do the thing you want, consider running the first query separately instead.

Comment: @Marc.Gravell Thanks for your answer will consider running the first query seperately and load succeeding entities after the first one is determined.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc Gravell had already gave you a hint but apart from that below code might help you.

Let say you have this type of model.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<Return> Returns { get; set; }
}
```

And here is your method.

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var customerList = new List<Customer>();

    string query = "SELECT Id, " +
                    "[Name] FROM Customers";

    string subsetquery = @"select * from Orders where CustomerId = @Id;
                            select * from Returns where CustomerId = @Id";

    customerList = _connection.Query<Customer>(query);

    foreach (var item in customerList)
    {
        var oPara = new DynamicParameters();
        oPara.Add("@Id", item.Id, dbType: DbType.Int32);

        using (var multi = _connection.QueryMultiple(subsetquery, oPara, commandType: CommandType.Text))
        {
            item.orders = multi.Read<Order>();
            item.returns = multi.Read<Return>();
        }
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

**NOTE:** Above code is not tested in VS. So you may have to change as per your requirement.